# Passing in parameter to where clause using IS NULL or Coalesce

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to pass in a parameter `@CompanyID` into a `where` clause to filter results. But sometimes this value may be `null` so I want all records to be returned. I have found two ways of doing this, but am not sure which one is the safest.

Version 1

```
SELECT ProductName, CompanyID 
FROM Products 
WHERE (@CompanyID IS NULL OR CompanyID = @CompanyID)
```

Version 2

```
SELECT ProductName, CompanyID 
FROM Products 
WHERE CompanyID = COALESCE(@CompanyID, CompanyID)
```

I have found that the first version is the quickest, but I have also found in other tables using a similar method that I get different result sets back. I don't quite understand the different between the two.

Can anyone please explain?

Comment: For one the second is not valid syntax.  Cannot explain different results if you don't provide valid syntax and data to reproduce.

Comment: @Paparazzi It was a oversight. I've added in the correct syntax.

Comment: Dude attention to detail.  Why is CompanyID on other side of the `=` ?  Why parens on the first.  Stuff like that is lead to stupid stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, both queries are handling the same two scenarios -
In one scenario `@CompanyID` contains a value,
and in the second `@CompanyID` contains `NULL`.

For both queries, the first scenario will return the same result set - since 
if `@CompanyId` contains a value, both will return all rows where `companyId = @CompanyId`, however the first query might return it faster (more on that at the end of my answer).

The second scenario, however, is where the queries starts to behave differently.

First, this is why you get different result sets:

**Difference in result sets**

> Version 1

```
WHERE (@CompanyID IS NULL OR CompanyID = @CompanyID)
```

When `@CompanyID` is null, the where clause will not filter out any rows whatsoever, and all the records in the table will be returned.

> Version 2

```
WHERE CompanyID = COALESCE(@CompanyID, CompanyID)
```

When `@CompanyID` is null, the where clause will filter out all the rows where `CompanyID` is null, since the result of `null = null` is actually `unknown` - and any query with `null = null` as it's where clause will return no results, unless [`ANSI_NULLS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql) is set to `OFF` (which you really should not do since it's deprecated).

**Index usage**

You might get faster results from the first version, since the use of any function on a column in the where clause will prevent SQL Server from using any index that you might have on this column.
You can read more about it on [this article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1236/avoid-sql-server-functions-in-the-where-clause-for-performance/) in MSSql Tips.

**Conclusion**

Version 1 is better than version 2. 
Even if you do not want to return records where `companyId` is null it's still better to write as `WHERE (@CompanyID IS NULL OR CompanyID = @CompanyID) AND CompanyID IS NOT NULL` than to use the second version.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth noting that using the syntax `([Column] = @Value OR [Column] IS NULL)` is a much better idea than using `ISNULL([Column],@Value) = @Value` (or using `COALESCE`).

This is because using the function causes the query to become un-SARGable; so indexes won't be used. The first expression is SARGable, and thus, will perform better.

Just adding this, as the OP states "I have found that the first version is the quickest", and wanted to elaborate why (even though, currently the statement is incomplete, I am *guessing* this was more due to user error and ignorance).

Comment: Then I am also ignorant as I have cases of isnull performing faster.  The `or` can make for an ugly query plan.

Comment: @Paparazzi My comment on the ignorance was due to the OP's expression simply being `WHERE COALESCE(@Value,[Column])` (so it isn't a boolean expression), not about the SARGability. The `OR` can cause a poor query lan, which is more than likely due to other reasons (such as parameter sniffing, or odd indexing), provided you don't have loads of `OR`s. If you do, then it sounds like a "catch-all" query, and they have their own problems. Either way, it doesn't change the fact that neither `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` is SARGable.

Answer (score 0):

The second version is not correct SQL (for SQL Server).  It needs an operator.  Presumably:

```
SELECT ProductName, CompanyID 
FROM Products 
WHERE COALESCE(@CompanyID, CompanyID) = CompanyID;
```

The first version is correct as written.  If you have an index on `CompanyID`, you might find this faster:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Products 
WHERE CompanyID = @CompanyID
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM Products 
WHERE @CompanyID IS NULL;
```