# How to check if condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am using SQL Server stored procedures. In my form I have one mandatory field `date` and one optional field `sizeid`. There is two scenarios to retrieve data

1. optional field not empty
2. optional field empty

T-SQL query

```
select * 
from product
where date = '4/03/2018'
  and (case when @param is not null then sizeid = @param end)
```

When optional field is empty, I don't want to check the condition, if it is there then I want to check

I hope somebody will help me soon

Comment: What's the error message you get?

Comment: read about [catch-all queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31933431/sql-server-2008-r2-prepare-dynamic-where-clause/31933677#31933677)

Answer (score 4):

Use `OR`. 
Also, use `yyyy-MM-dd` format for dates.

```
select * 
from product 
where date = '2018-03-04' and
      (@param is null or sizeid = @param)
```

Comment: I took the liberty of making the query correct, because this is the most upvoted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL syntax does not seem correct because if your `CASE` statement evaluates to false, then it does not return anything so your `AND` clause has nothing to compute. I would try something like this:

```
select * from product
where date='4/03/2018'
and sizeid= case when @param is not null
then @param else sizeid end
```

Comment: this is incorrect syntax for SQL Server. you might want to try something like `and sizeid= case when @param is not null then @param else sizeid end`.

Answer (score 0):

Just another option using `IsNull()` and `NullIf()`.  This way if `@param=''` it would be processed as null.

The `NullIf()` is optional.

```
select * 
 From product 
 where date='2018-03-04' 
   and sizeid=IsNull(NullIf(@param,''),sizeid)
```

Comment: There are a couple of problems with this suggestion: `IsNull(NullIf(` is not sargable, and will also not return any records where sizeid is null unless ansi-nulls is set to off. [Read here for more details.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49092637/3094533)

Comment: @ZoharPeled It is resolved once and optimized.  Take a peek at http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqlyse-with-pankaj-manek/2015/08/20/isnull-around-the-predicate-and-sargability/

Comment: are you sure that's the correct link? All that article claims is that `ISNULL` is sargable on non nullable columns....

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the link, I've just used it in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49105875/better-approach-of-conditional-column-query/49109415#49109415) :-)