# Better approach of conditional column query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

```
--OldQuery
SELECT oldStartDate AS column,...
FROM Table
WHERE
oldStartDate > @date,...
GROUP BY
oldStartDate,...
```

There is a new column `newStartDate` nullable added to the table and data extraction has to be conditionally depending on this column

```
--NewQuery
SELECT ISNULL(newStartDate, oldStartDate) AS column,...
FROM Table
WHERE
(    
    (newStartDate IS NULL AND oldStartDate > @date)
    OR 
    (newStartDate > @date)
),...
GROUP BY
ISNULL(newStartDate, oldStartDate),...
```

Above is the approach I can think of to retrieve conditionally however it seems to me will cause performance issue and I can't evaluate in `DEV` environment as volume is not big enough but production is estimating roughly 2mil records. Wondering if there is any other recommended approach instead?

Comment: I would say just try running the query and compare the performance to the old one.  There is nothing about your query which has a smell per se.  Try it and then decide.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use `ISNULL` in the `GROUP BY` clause you might as well also use in in the `WHERE` clause, since both would make the `newStartDate` un sargable, [because the column is nullable.](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqlyse-with-pankaj-manek/2015/08/20/isnull-around-the-predicate-and-sargability/) (Thanks for the link, John Cappelletti!)

Assuming the `NewStartDate` will replace the `OldStartDate`, one thing you can do to is update all the null values in `newStartDate` to the non-null values of `oldStartDate`, and then alter your `newStartDate` column as a non-nullable column:

```
UPDATE TableName
SET NewStartDate = OldStartDate
WHERE NewStartDate IS NULL;
GO

ALTER TABLE TableName
    ALTER COLUMN NewStartDate date NOT NULL;
GO
```

Then your query can be much simpler and sargable:

```
SELECT NewStartDate AS column,...
FROM Table
WHERE
NewStartDate > @date,...
GROUP BY
NewStartDate ,...
```